# geanyvc on windows

Tags: windows, git, geany

I've installed the geanyvc plugin for Geany (1.22) and GTK+ bundle in Windows 7 64bit, which provides version control functions inside Geany, however I can't use the plugin's function; the menu entries are greyed out. It seems that Geany doesn't recognize my repository (i'm using git). I've tried opening an existing file in my local clone and creating a new one inside of it but the result is the same.

Searching over the net I haven't found anything useful, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin depends on git. You can download git for windows from this website: http://msysgit.github.io/

And, I think you will have to edit you %PATH% variable so that the plugin finds the git executables.

Also, take a look at that discussion from the geany-users mailing list: http://geany-users.466218.n3.nabble.com/Geany-VC-on-Windows-td3046632.html . It might answer some questions.

Oh, and use this mailing list. You will most certainly get a quick answer.